# PREG_MATCH a-z, A-Z, 0-9 fullstop and forwardslash

Tags: php, html, scripting, preg-match

I need to validate some data and confirm that the pattern contains only `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `full-stop` or a `forward slash`.

```
if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ./]*$/",$field)) {  
 $fielderror = "Field can only contain a-z A-Z 0-9 . /";
}
```

However, it seems to allow other special characters e.g.: `@ # and $`.

any thoughts?  Thinking i am missing something really obvious....

Comment: Maybe you should try other delimiters in your expression. (First and last chars `/`)

Comment: Hi, if my answer solved your question, please flag it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has an error:

> E_WARNING : type 2 -- preg_match(): Unknown modifier ']' -- at line 4

```
$field = "123";
//$field = "@*";


if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9 \.\/]+g/",$field)) {  
echo "Field can only contain a-z A-Z 0-9 . /";
} else {
echo "its ok";
}
```

You can use this `regex`:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9\.\/]+
```

Comment: Thanks Pedram, I gave this a try and whilst it works IF an invalid character is at the start, it does not seem to pickup if it is at the end.

eg: $field = "Pizza@" seems to still get classed as ok. Any thoughts? 

Note: i tried your code here [link](http://phptester.net/) incase there is an issue with my php config etc.

Comment: @Samuel Answer updated. Please check again.

Comment: I was still able to key invalid characters, however this was mostliky because i was not using preg_match_all.

in the end the code i used was:
    $p = '/[a-zA-Z0-9 \.\/]+/';
    $psw1 = "password./";
    preg_match_all($p, $psw1, $matches);
    $chkd = strlen(implode('', $matches[0]));
    if ($chkd != strlen($psw1)) {  
    $p1err = "Password can only contain a-z A-Z 0-9 . /";
     }

Answer (score 1):

You must only escape the `/` because is used as delimiter (is present at the start and end of the pattern):

```
if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9 .\/]*$/",$field)) {  
 $fielderror = "Field can only contain a-z A-Z 0-9 . /";
}
```

See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) for more information about [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) used in the regex.